# SQL server - Incorrect syntax near 'select'. Expecting '.', ID or quoted id

Tags: sql-server

i been facing error as title, how should i fix the error?
below was my code

```
select *
from (
select outletcode, date, amount
from bills
) as A
PIVOT 
(
sum(amount)
FOR outletcode IN
(select distinct outletcode from bills)
) as B;
```

Comment: please share your table structure as it easier to do troubleshooting.

Comment: you need to specify the list of `outletcode`  in the `IN` part in the `PIVOT` operator. You cannot use a query there. If the list is unknown or dynamic, you need to use a dynamic query. Please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: You need to use dynamic sql to create dynamic pivots like this. There's probably at least one question per day about it, so it shouldn't be hard to find